# Activity with fragment

Tags: android, text, view, fragment, adapter

I am new to the Android world and I find it complex to say the least. I'm making a small app to better understand the operation of the activity and the fragment. My goal is to have 10 screens. These screens must also contain a string over an image different from the others. This is my code regarding the class of the first fragment which will have the blue background.

```
package pl.looksok.viewpagerdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class FragmentBlue extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blue, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

This will be the page that will contain a different name. The problem here is that I can not put any Text View, because I extended the class fragment and not the Activity.In this file instead do a loop that I die 11 times before the page generated

```
package pl.looksok.viewpagerdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

        for(int i = 0; i<=10; i++){
            fragments.add(new FragmentBlue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }
}
```

Finally, this is the Main activity

```
    package pl.looksok.viewpagerdemo;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyPagerAdapter pageAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    }
}
```

I would that every activity has a text view that molds a different result for each page. Who knows how to help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<Fragment> fragments ;
fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
for(int i = 0; i<=10; i++){
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentBlue.class.getName()));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment class create a static method to get a fragment with the color, image and text desired ...

```
public static Fragment getFragmentWithColorImageAndText(int color, int imageRes, String text) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("color",color);
    bundle.putInt("image",image);
    bundle.putString("text",text);
    YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}
```

then in your fragments onCreate or onCreateView do

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
String text = bundle.getString("text");
YOUR_TEXTVIEW.setText(text);
```

...same with color (setBackground...) and image...(YOUR_IMAGEVIEW.setImage...)

Now when you want to create a fragment you just have to do ...

```
YourFragment.getFragmentWithColorImageAndText(Color.BLUE, R.drawable.imageRes, "Hello World");
```